# Two-finger scroll triggers right-click [Synaptics, Windows 10]

Tags: windows-10, hp-laptop, synaptics-touchpad

Have an HP laptop 15-g088ca with touchpad running latest Synaptics driver 9.3.31.31 (8/16/2017). Two-finger scrolling and two-finger right-click both work, but when I do a fast two-finger scroll it finishes by invoking a right-click. E.g., running Chrome, if I do a quick two-finger swipe upward (only touch the pad for a split second), the page scrolls and then the right-click context menu pops up. If I do a slower swipe (touch the pad for a half second), then it scrolls fine (no context menu).

I went thru the settings but couldn't find a fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out rolling back the driver fixed the problem. In Windows 10 Device Manager I selected the driver and chose "update driver" which give me the 2017 driver and the problems. On the HP support page for my device, they only list 19.0.12.104 (9/19/2015) as the most recent update. So, uninstalling the drive and installing the HP-approved driver solved the problem.

EDIT:

Just check my driver version and it updated back to the 2017 driver in my OP that gave me trouble, but now the problem's gone. Guessing a Windows update fixed the problem?

Comment: Please mark this as the correct answer so that other people with the same issue will know that this is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Search for Touchpad Settings > Additional Settings > under tab "TouchStyk" in Button actions set "Right Button Action" to "Button/Zone completely disabled" from the drop down.

do same under the tab "TouchPad" and apply.

Things should work fine now.

Comment: Glad this worked for you but there's no TouchStyk in the model PC listed in my OP, so no TouchStyk tab